# Data is not saving in database after editing - MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a gridview in MVC, when I click on edit that specific row turns into textboxes but the data isn't updated. the data I changed isn't saved after hitting tab or enter there is previous record.
what do I have to change the code to get my result?

my jQuery code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('a.edit').click(function () {
                var dad = $(this).parent().parent();
                dad.find('.displaytext').hide();
                dad.find('input[type="text"]').show();
            });

        $('input[type=text]').focusout(function() {
            var dad = $(this).parent();
            $(this).hide();
            dad.find('.displaytext').show();
        });
        });
    </script>
```

my controller code for edit is

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            tbl_HolidayList tbl_holidaylist = db.tbl_HolidayList.Find(id);
            if (tbl_holidaylist == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(tbl_holidaylist);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Holiday/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(tbl_HolidayList tbl_holidaylist)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(tbl_holidaylist).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                TempData["Msg"] = "Data has been updated succeessfully";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(tbl_holidaylist);
        }
```

html code

```
<table>
        <tr>
@*            <th>
                @Html.Label("ID")
            </th>*@
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Name")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Description")
            </th>
            <th>
                 @Html.Label("Date")
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
           @* <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Id, new { style = "display: none; width:170px; height:15px" })
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Id)
                </div>
            </td>*@
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Name, new { style = "display: none; width:170px; height:15px" })
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Name)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Description, new { style = "display: none; width:170px; height:15px" })
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Description)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_date, new { style = "display: none; width:170px; height:15px" })
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_date)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a id="edit" class="edit" href="#">Edit</a> |
                @*@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Holiday_Id }, new { @class = "lnkEdit" }) |*@
               @* @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Holiday_Id}, new { @class = "lnkDetail" }) |*@
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Holiday_Id }, new { @class = "lnkDelete" })
                @*<a id="edit" class="edit" href="#">Edit</a> |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Holiday")*@
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
```

Comment: Would help if you provided the html markup for a cell

Comment: All you code is doing is showing textboxes and hiding then when it loses focus. you don't update the text in the table row, nor do you have any method of saving the data to the database (no form or ajax to post the data). Your also creating invalid html (duplicate id attributes).

Answer (score 1):

Your current code doesn't transfer the values between the text in display and the value of the input

Without seeing the html you could try something like the following:

```
$('a.edit').click(function () {
    var dad = $(this).parent().parent();
    var $display = dad.find('.displaytext').hide();
    /* get recent text */
    var txt = $display.text();
    /* use val() to update input */
    dad.find('input[type="text"]').val(txt).show();
});

$('input[type=text]').focusout(function () {
    var dad = $(this).parent();
    $(this).hide();
    /* use input value to update text */
    var val = this.value;
    /* do ajax here to update server if needed */
    dad.find('.displaytext').text(val).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an inline grid editing page specific based plugin a while ago, Here is how I have this worked-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function siblingsEditor(ele) {
        $(ele).parent().parent('tr').siblings().children('td').not(':first-child').not(':last-child').each(function () {
            var values;
            if ($(this).children().is('input[type="text"]')) {
                values = $(this).children('input').val();
            }
            else {
                values = $(this).children('label').text();
            }
            var nameofthiselement = $(this).attr('data-target');
            $(this).html('<label for="' + nameofthiselement + '">' + values + '</label>');
        });
    }

    function Edit(element, id) {
        siblingsEditor(element);
        $(element).hide();
        $(element).next().show();
        $(element).next().next().show();
        $(element).parent().parent('tr').children('td').not(':first-child').not(':last-child').each(function () {
            var nameofthiselement = $(this).children().attr('for');
            $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" name="' + nameofthiselement + '" value="' + $(this).children('label').html() + '"></input>');
        });
    }
    function Cancel(element, id) {
        $(element).hide();
        $(element).prev().show();
        $(element).next().hide();
        $(element).prev().prev().show();
        $(element).parent().parent('tr').children('td').not(':first-child').not(':last-child').each(function () {
            var values;
            if ($(this).children().is('input[type="text"]')) {
                values = $(this).children('input').val();
            }
            else {
                values = $(this).children('label').text();
            }
            var nameofthiselement = $(this).attr('data-target');
            $(this).html('<label for="' + nameofthiselement + '">' + values + '</label>');
        });
    }
    function Update(element, id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Controller/Action?ID=' + id,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $(element).hide();
                $(element).prev().hide();
                $(element).prev().prev().show();
                $(element).parent().parent('tr').children('td').not(':first-child').not(':last-child').each(function () {
                    var values;
                    if ($(this).children().is('input[type="text"]')) {
                        values = $(this).children('input').val();
                    }
                    else {
                        values = $(this).children('label').text();
                    }
                    var nameofthiselement = $(this).attr('data-target');
                    $(this).html('<label for="' + nameofthiselement + '">' + values + '</label>');
                });
            }
        });
    }
    function Delete(element, id) {
        $.post({'/controller/Actiion?ID=' + id,function (data) {
            $(element).parent().parent().fadeOut();
        }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Note-**
I restricted table to be in specific structure where `for` attribute must match `data-target` of table column-

```
<form id="form">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>S.NO.
            </th>
            <th>header1
            </th>
            <th>header2
            </th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>column1</td>
                    <td data-target="samename1">
                        <label for="samename1">some html</label>
                    </td>
                    <td data-target="samename2">
                        <label for="samename2">some html</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="javacript:;" onclick="Edit(this,1)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                        <a href="javacript:;"  style="display:none" onclick="Cancel(this,'idofthisrow')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                        <a href="javacript:;"  style="display:none" onclick="Update(this,'idofthisrow')"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a>
                        <a href="javacript:;"  onclick="Delete(this,1)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

And then columns those I didn't want to edit, I put them in jQuery `.not`.

Try it and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this in controller

```
     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(tbl_HolidayList tbl_holidaylist)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

               List<tbl_HolidayList > holitemp = new List<tbl_HolidayList >();
            foreach (tbl_HolidayList item in objedit.tbl_HolidayList )
            {
                 if (item.Holiday_Name== null || item.Holiday_Name.Trim() == "")
                {
                    if (item.Holiday_Id!= 0)
                    {
                        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                    else
                        holitemp .Add(item);
                }
                else if (item.Holiday_Id== 0)
                    db.tbl_HolidayList .Add(item);

                else
                    db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;


            }

            foreach (tbl_HolidayList item in holitemp)
            {
                if (item.Holiday_Name== 0 || item.Holiday_Name== null)
                {
                    objedit.tbl_HolidayList .Remove(item);
                }
            }
```

Comment: null is coming in parameter, throw exception on SaveChanges()`

Comment: if null is coming try the above.